# Why are the two calculations of $ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \mathrm{d} x $ give two distinct answers?

Tags: calculus, integration

One of the calculations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \mathrm{d} x &=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x})^{2}}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{~d} x \\
&=2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x})^{2}}} \mathrm{~d}(\sqrt{x})=2 \arcsin \sqrt{x}+C .
\end{aligned}
$$
The other:
$$ 
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \mathrm{d} x = \int \frac{d\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}} = \arcsin \frac{x-1 / 2}{1 / 2}+C=\arcsin(2x-1)+C
$$

Comment: The formula for $\cos{2u}=2\cos{u}^2-1$ can be used to get a relation between the two forms of arcsin appearing in the results and thus show both answers are equivalent.

Comment: There is no problem: the functions on the r.h.s. are the same except for an additive constant

Answer (score 6):

The answers are actually the same.

$\begin{align*}
\theta = 2\arcsin \sqrt x &\implies \sin \frac \theta 2 = \sqrt x \\
&\implies \sin^2 \frac \theta 2 = x \\
&\implies \frac{1-\cos \theta}{2} = x \\
&\implies \cos \theta = 1-2x \\
&\implies \sin(\theta+\pi/2) = 2x-1 \\
&\implies \theta = \arcsin(2x-1) - \pi/2
\end{align*}$

And $\pi/2$ gets absorbed into $+C$

Answer (score 0):

Because the integral is indefinite.

If you differentiate the first form,
$${d2\arcsin{(\sqrt{x})} \over dx}=2{1 \over \sqrt{1-(\sqrt{x})^2}}\cdot {1 \over 2\sqrt{x}}={1 \over \sqrt{x(1-x)}}$$

As for the second one,
$${d\arcsin{(2x-1)} \over dx}={1 \over \sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2}}\cdot 2={1 \over \sqrt{x(1-x)}}$$

Therefore, the both forms are correct.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct. Let $y=2 \arcsin \sqrt x$. Then $x=(\sin (\frac  y 2))^{2}$. So $2x-1=2(\sin (\frac  y 2))^{2}-1=\sin (y+\frac {\pi} 2)$. So $y=\sin (2x-1)-\frac {\pi} 2$.